# Search/replace with special characters in macro variable

Tags: regex, sas

`%let st1 = a b c;`

I would like to do a search/replace to get a new macro variable like this

`%let st2 = a_b_c;`

or

`%let st3 = a%b%c;`

or

`%let st3 = a!!b!!c;`

Basically just replace certain char  with `_` or `%` or `!!`.

I think `prxchange` is fastest way to go (even faster than `tranwrd`). But I'm struggling with its syntax.

Here's what I have tried

`%put %sysfunc(prxchange(s/(\w+)/\1_/,-1,%bquote(&st1)));`

Comment: Why is performance a concern here? If you're doing this with so many macro variables that you're noticing a difference then perhaps a data step approach might be worth considering?

Comment: Not really a concern. Just being curious about the efficient way to deal with such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex needs some work. I've changed the regex based on your requirement i.e ! _ % needs to be updated by space.

```
%let st1 = a b c;
%let st2 = a_b_c;
%let st3 = %nrstr(a%b%c);
%let st4 = a!!b!!c;
%put %sysfunc(prxchange(s/[\_\!\%]/ /,-1,%bquote(&st2)));
%put %sysfunc(prxchange(s/[\_\!\%]/ /,-1,%bquote(&st3)));
%put %sysfunc(prxchange(s/[\_\!\%]/ /,-1,%bquote(&st4)));
```

Hope this help. Thanks!!

**UPDATE:**

providing updated prxchange function to replace !! with single space. Also, replacement happens from left to right. we cannot make it do from right to left.

```
%let st1 = a b c;
%let st2 = a_b_c;
%let st3 = %nrstr(a%b%c);
%let st4 = a!!b!!c;
%put %sysfunc(prxchange(s/([\_\%])|(!!)/ /,-1,%bquote(&st2)));
%put %sysfunc(prxchange(s/([\_\%])|(!!)/ /,-1,%bquote(&st3)));
%put %sysfunc(prxchange(s/([\_\%])|(!!)/ /,-1,%bquote(&st4)));
```

Comment: Please noted that the last one is not equals to first two. Because you replace `!!` with `__`, not `_`.